# Fatal error encounterd when using MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader, mysql.data

I'm getting the following error at my C# WinForms application:

> fatal error encountered during data read

I'm using `mysql.data V4.0.30319`.

Here's my code:

```
int catCount = 1;     
while (catCount < 13)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=server;user id=user;password=password;database=db;");
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader Rd;
    string query = "SELECT oc_newsletter_old_system.email FROM oc_newsletter_old_system WHERE oc_newsletter_old_system.cat_uid = "  + catCount;
    MySqlCommand mC = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    Rd = mC.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {      
        while (Rd.Read())
        {
            string email = Rd.GetString(0);
            Boolean insert = true;
            int realCat = 0;
            switch (catCount)
            {
                case '1':
                    fileBrian += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '2':
                    fileDunamis += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '3':
                    fileFrohlich += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '4':
                    fileGaithers += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '5':
                    fileGospel7 += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '6':
                    fileLifeshop += email + "\r\n";
                    realCat = 1;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    fileMeyer += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '8':
                    fileOpwekking += email + "\r\n";
                    break;
                case '9':
                    filePelgrimKerken += email + "\r\n";
                    realCat = 2;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    filePelgrimKlanten += email + "\r\n";
                    realCat = 2;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    filePelgrimPers += email + "\r\n";
                    insert = false;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    filePelgrimScholen += email + "\r\n";
                    insert = false;
                    break;
            }

            if (insert == true)
            {    
                string salt = "h1bsqnp6wyxjxhf29ziuwsihg8nixe05";
                byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + email);
                byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
                string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                string query2 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `oc_ne_marketing` (`email`,`code`, `subscribed`, `store_id`) VALUES ('" + email + "', '" + hashedString + "', '1', '" + realCat + "')";
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=server;user id=user;password=password;database=db;");
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection);
                    cmd1.CommandText = query2;
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Rd.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

    catCount++;
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    progressBar1.Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I'm getting the error at this line:

```
while (Rd.Read())
```

The only thing that i found out so far was an problem with closing the reader and connection, but as far as i know is that all setup right...

So do you guys got any idea what's the matter???

Comment: Can you try parameterized queries?

Comment: @nawfal, i can try, but i don't think that's necessary... The first query takes only integers, and the second takes only save ( already in the DB ) data. Also the problem is at an reader. So do you really think that dat would fix the problem???

Comment: Do a google search for this problem. It yields some results. Seems like a bug. strange indeed. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61807 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546115/mysql-exception-fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131429/fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read

Comment: Why are you using try blocks with no catch?  Put in a catch block in your try/finally and see if that reveals any further information.

Comment: @Tim, i'm using that to always close everything, even when en error happans. And this is inside an another try, with an catch, and that gives this error..

Comment: @Mathlight - Use `using` blocks instead of try/finally - they will clean up the resources even if an exception occurs.

Comment: @Tim, could u make an answer of that ( with some code )? I'm pretty new to that...

Comment: Sure...give me a few minutes.

Comment: @nawfal, thanks for the bug link. I'm trying the work around they provided. Be back in 10 minuts...

Comment: @nawfal, it looks like that the work around in that bug link you provided did the trick. If you can provide an answer of it i can accept it. `"The workaround then was to customize the net_xxx_timeout settings.
For example, issue the following after openning your connection and
before executing the datareader:

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
  "set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", con );
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
"`

Comment: @Mathlight I answered, but I will vote to close this as duplicate..

Comment: @nawfal, rules are rules ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A2A, for the sake of completeness.

From [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61807):

> The workaround then was to customize the net_xxx_timeout settings. For
>   example, issue the following after openning your connection and before
>   executing the datareader:

```
var c = new MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", con);
c.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here's source from `MySql.Data` in connection class:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (State == ConnectionState.Open)
    Close();
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

which basically means disposing is enough to close it (its bizarre otherwise). [Same holds true for `SqlConnection` too..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195829/do-i-have-to-close-a-sqlconnection-before-it-gets-disposed?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

While not a direct answer to your problem, per your request here's some info and a code example on `using`.

It's generally accepted best practice to use `using` statements with objects that implement `IDisposable` - it essentially does the same thing as a try/finally block.

Once the scope of the using statement is exited (either the operation completes or an exception is thrown), `Dispose` will be called on the object.  See [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Here's an abbreviated example based on your code:

```
int catCount = 1;     
string connectionString = "server=server;user id=user;password=password;database=db;"
string query = "SELECT email FROM oc_newsletter_old_system WHERE cat_uid=@cat_uid";

while (catCount < 13)
{

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand mC = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        mC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_uid", catCount);

        using (MySqlDataReader Rd = mC.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (Rd.Read())
            {

                 // rest of your code here
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Note that the above is based on the .NET SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader classes, but should be the same (or very similar) for MySql.

I moved the connection string and query string to their own variables (but that's a personal preference).  I also gave an example of how to do parameterized queries (the `mCParameters.AddWithValue` line - getting in the habit of using parmaeterized queries is (IMO) a good thing, especially if you move from WinForms to web-based apps, as it prevents SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But 1 thing about the connection. The say that you have to close instead ( or on top ) of the dispose. Where do i close the connection then ( even when an exception has thrown )

Comment: Where did you see that?  I would expect a properly implemented `Dispose` would close the existing connection - I've never explicitly closed a SqlConnection.  Perhaps it's something unique to MySql?

Comment: See this SO answer - Dispose closes the SqlConnection:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1195854/745969  Again, MySql might be doing it differently.

Comment: It got something to do with the connection pool. this of there documentation some where menthoid [here in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/61171/1846175)

`"It then releases the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled." So Close() should be sufficient to keep the connection pool from overflowing`

Comment: @Mathlight I have been using MySQL for a long time now, you dont have to dispose or close. Just wrap it in `using` clause, its enough..

Comment: @nawfal, alright then. From now on i will try to always use `using`. Thanks a lot Tim ;)