# Asyncpoco issue - Datareader premature end of stream MySQL and c#

Tags: c#, mysql, petapoco

Is there a way to set the net_write_timeout when using AsyncPoco?

I am getting a premature end of stream error from MySQL when using AsynchPoco processing a large recordset.

The issue is described in here - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57365

Another direct example is here - [MySQL Exception - Fatal Error Encountered During Data Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546115/mysql-exception-fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read)

Here is my code.

```
List<T> list = new List<T>();
var db = new AsyncPoco.Database(this.ConnectionString, this.ProvideName);
db.CommandTimeout = 2000;

db.QueryAsync<T>(sql, a =>
{
    list.Add(a);
}).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
await db.ExecuteAsync("set net_write_timeout = 31536000");
```